# What causes CudaAPIError: Call to cuLinkCreate results in CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOUT

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, numba, jit

I've been studying numba and tried to run this code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, cuda, vectorize
import math

@cuda.jit
def increment_a_2D_array(an_array):
    x, y = cuda.grid(2)
    if x < an_array.shape[0] and y < an_array.shape[1]:
       an_array[x, y] += 1
an_array = np.ones((10,10))

threadsperblock = (16, 16)
blockspergrid_x = math.ceil(an_array.shape[0] / threadsperblock[0])
blockspergrid_y = math.ceil(an_array.shape[1] / threadsperblock[1])
blockspergrid = (blockspergrid_x, blockspergrid_y)
increment_a_2D_array[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](an_array)
```

So when i run the code above it returns the following error:

**CudaAPIError: Call to cuLinkCreate results in CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_TIMEOU**

What could it be?

Comment: "cudaErrorLaunchTimeout = 702
This indicates that the device kernel took too long to execute."

Comment: The timeout is triggered by the display driver trying to protect CUDA code from freezing the display. It is unusual that it would be triggered by such a toy example, which suggests you might have hardware or software installation issues of some sort.